# Sequential exeution of operations that modify UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ui-thread, android-priority-jobqueue

Actual work is being done in `Asynctask`, the `AsyncTask` returns the results. Users need visual cue as to what happened behind the scenes, which involves multiple independent UI modifications to be done, sequentially. UI modifications involve animations so the next job in queue has to wait for the animation of current job to finish. [the sequence is not fixed, but varies according to the result received by `AsyncTask`.]

All heavy lifting like network access is done by `AsyncTask`, I am looking for a better way to modify the UI sequentially.

**My Current Approach:**
Currently I am using https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue

When a UI modification finishes, it sends out event on eventbus, and `jobManager` is started[it is stopped when a `job`'s `onRun` is called].

I am currently posting on UI handler inside `onRun` of the `Job`. 
It works, but the library is designed for writing to disks and long running operations and not UI operations. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your question: A more elegant solution is a quite tough metric to determine whether an answer might be suitable for you or not.

Comment: @Baschi clarified.

Answer (score -1):

put your UI modification inside the **onPostExecute** method of your AsyncTask, it runs on the UI thread by default so you can update it from there after your whole loading is finished in doInBackground.

If you immediately want to do this inside **doInBackground**, use the following method inside that method.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

  public void run(){

  //your ui updations here
  }

});
```

Set an animation Listener to each animation and use onAnimationEnd to trigger next animation here:

```
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
   //trigger next animation here to make it sequential
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
});
```

This will help batching and maintaining sequences of animations

Comment: I need batch UI operations. New UI operations need previous Animations to finish. which will not happen in this case.

Comment: then i second @dipdipdip, use Rxjava with RetroLambda. read up on it to get a clear picture, its quite complicated to explain here.

Comment: `Message queues. Queues like in MSMQ or a JMS implementation generally have transactionality and are by definition sequential`. and RxJava is not recommended for that usecase from : introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html#WhyRx. Also could you provide some pointers as to how to implement job queue in RxJava?

Comment: use setAnimationListener on each animation. It provides an onAnimationEnd method. here you can trigger your next animation

Comment: I am currently using that approach only. Do you know, how to implement job queue in rxjava?

Comment: not used it like that, sorry :( I just use it to jump and handle threads.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend you to use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)!

- You will get rid of the AsyncTask
- Your Logik seems a bit more difficult and you want to jump between different Threads. RxJava will help you a lot with it.

Hint: You also should use [Retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) to make RxJava your Code cleaner.

Comment: `Message queues. Queues like in MSMQ or a JMS implementation generally have transactionality and are by definition sequential.`  and RxJava is not recommended for that usecase from : http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html#WhyRx 

Also how we implement job queue in RxJava?

Comment: I don't think you can compare this statement to your problem. Two advantages of RxJava are a simplification of complex flows and (android specific) easy way to jump between different Threads: Worker and Main Thread in your case. I guess its a bit more complicated to give an implementation of a job queue with the given information but it should definitely be possible with RxJava.

Comment: And the site I mentioned says not to use RxJava for job queues.